# Send right click to a window

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, sendmessage, right-click

I'm trying to send a right mouse click to a window specified coordinates.

I've tested with 2 codes

Code 1:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]        
static extern bool ScreenToClient(IntPtr hWnd, ref POINT lpPoint);

public struct POINT
{
    public int x;
    public int y;
}

var client = Process.GetProcessesByName("client_dx");
var whandle = client.MainWindowHandle;

POINT point = new POINT();
point.x = 1836;
point.y = 325;
ScreenToClient(whandle, ref point);
int lparm = (point.x << 16) + point.y;    
int lngResult = SendMessage(whandle, 0x0204, 0, lparm);
int lngResult2 = SendMessage(whandle, 0x0205, 0, lparm);
```

Code 2:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]        
static extern bool ScreenToClient(IntPtr hWnd, ref POINT lpPoint);

public struct POINT
{
    public int x;
    public int y;
}

public int MakeLParam(int LoWord, int HiWord)
{
    return (int)((HiWord << 16) | (LoWord & 0xFFFF));
}

var client = Process.GetProcessesByName("client_dx");
var whandle = client.MainWindowHandle;

POINT point = new POINT();
point.x = 1836;
point.y = 325;

ScreenToClient(whandle, ref point);

int lparm = MakeLParam(point.x, point.y);
int lngResult = SendMessage(whandle, 0x0204, 0, lparm);
int lngResult2 = SendMessage(whandle, 0x0205, 0, lparm);
```

It's sending a right click but not to the correct coordinates, seems like it ignores the coordinates I specify in LPARAM, because if I move the mouse around the window, it's clicking everywhere I put the mouse pointer but not in the coordinates that I specify.

I've tested changing this line in code 2:

```
int lparm = MakeLParam(point.x, point.y);
```

To this one:

```
int lparm = (point.x << 16) + point.y;
```

But doesn't work, I'm getting the same results...

Comment: Did you test/check the coordinates returned (by ref) to the point structure by ScreenToClient() ?

Comment: As @VillageTech is eluding to, the coordinates used are relative to the client window you are addressing, not the entire desktop. In the docs for WM_RBUTTONDOWN(/UP), it says "The coordinate is relative to the upper-left corner of the client area."

Comment: As you can see I'm "translating" the desktop coordinates to client coordinates.. ScreenToClient(whandle, ref point); But anyways if that was the case it doesn't explain why right click area is changing as I move my mouse, it's ignoring my coordinates

Comment: What VillageTech was referring to is you never check the bool returned by `ScreenToClient`, to see if the call was a success or failure.

Comment: Use `mouse_event`

Comment: Or if you want to use `SendMessage`, translate the window screen position to its relative position.

Comment: I've checked the ScreenToClient it's working with Debug.WriteLine and it's working.. @RezaAghaei if you take a look at the code, I'm using ScreenToClient to get the window relative coordinates

Comment: @kuhi Take a look at working examples in the answer below :)

Comment: At least in *Code 1* you have used wrong parameters to get `LParam`.

Answer (score 9):

You can use [`SendMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendmessage?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) or [`mouse_event`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-mouse_event?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) or [`SendInput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput)to perform a mouse operation. Here I will share some details and examples about the first two.

*Using SendMessage*

- `SendMessage` performs the mouse action without needing to move the cursor.
- `SendMessage` needs handle of the window to send message.
- `SendMessage` sends the mouse message to a relative position inside the window. The coordinate should be relative to the upper-left corner of the client area of the window.
- If you know which point in the client coordinate, you want to send click, then just use the client coordinates. It's usually the case.
- If you have a screen position and you want to translate it to client relative position, you can use `ScreenToClient`. But since you usually know the relative position you are going to click, you usually don't need [`ScreenToClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-screentoclient?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235).
- To pass parameters to [`MakeLParam`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-makelparam?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) the low-order word specifies the x-coordinate and high-order word specifies the y-coordinate of the cursor. To make it less confusing, use the following function:

  ```
  IntPtr MakeLParam(int x, int y) => (IntPtr)((y << 16) | (x & 0xFFFF));
  ```
- And as a side-note, if you want to the send the message to a window and return without waiting for the thread to process the message, you can use [`PostMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-postmessagew?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235).

*Using mouse_event*

- `mouse_event` Performs the mouse action on the current cursor position.
- Before calling `mouse_event` you need to move the cursor to the location on screen which you are going to perform click.
- To get screen position of a client point of a window, you can use [`ClientToScreen`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-clienttoscreen?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) method.
- To move the cursor you can set [`Cursor.Position`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.cursor.position?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) to a screen position.
- It's recommended to use `SendInput` function instead.

### Example 1 - SendMessage

Using `SendMessage` you can click on the specified relative position of a specified window. In the following example, I've found the `edit` control inside `notepad` main window, then I've performed a right click on `(20,20)` coordinate inside the client rectangle of the edit control:

```
//using System;
//using System.Diagnostics;
//using System.Drawing;
//using System.Linq;
//using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
//using System.Windows.Forms;
```

```
const int WM_RBUTTONDOWN = 0x0204;
const int WM_RBUTTONUP = 0x0205;
const int WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x0200;
[DllImport("User32.DLL")]
static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

IntPtr MakeLParam(int x, int y) => (IntPtr)((y << 16) | (x & 0xFFFF));

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter,
    string lpszClass, string lpszWindow);

void PerformRightClick(IntPtr hwnd, Point point)
{
    var pointPtr = MakeLParam(point.X, point.Y);
    SendMessage(hwnd, WM_MOUSEMOVE, IntPtr.Zero, pointPtr);
    SendMessage(hwnd, WM_RBUTTONDOWN, IntPtr.Zero, pointPtr);
    SendMessage(hwnd, WM_RBUTTONUP, IntPtr.Zero, pointPtr);
}
```

```
void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var notepad = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad").FirstOrDefault();
    if (notepad != null)
    {
        var edit = FindWindowEx(notepad.MainWindowHandle, IntPtr.Zero, "Edit", null);
        PerformRightClick(edit, new Point(20, 20));
    }
}
```

### Example 2 - mouse_event

Using `mouse_event` you can click on the current mouse position. It means you need to move the mouse to the desired location. In the following example, I've found the `edit` control inside `notepad` main window, then I've performed a right click on `(20,20)` coordinate inside the client rectangle of the edit control:

```
//using System;
//using System.Diagnostics;
//using System.Drawing;
//using System.Linq;
//using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
//using System.Windows.Forms;
```

```
const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = 0x0008;
const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = 0x0010;
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern void mouse_event(uint dwFlags, uint dx, uint dy,
    uint cButtons, uint dwExtraInfo);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter,
    string lpszClass, string lpszWindow);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct POINT { public int X; public int Y; }

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool ClientToScreen(IntPtr hWnd, ref POINT lpPoint);

void PerformRightClick(IntPtr hwnd, Point p)
{
    POINT point = new POINT() { X = p.X, Y = p.Y };
    ClientToScreen(hwnd, ref point);
    Cursor.Position = new Point(point.X, point.Y);
    uint X = (uint)Cursor.Position.X;
    uint Y = (uint)Cursor.Position.Y;
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP, X, Y, 0, 0);
}
```

```
void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var notepad = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad").FirstOrDefault();
    if (notepad != null)
    {
        var edit = FindWindowEx(notepad.MainWindowHandle, IntPtr.Zero, "Edit", null);
        PerformRightClick(edit, new Point(20, 20));
    }
}
```

Comment: You assigned the bounty, thanks. But didn't accepted/voted the answer. Looks like something is wrong with the answer? let me know if I can help you :)

Comment: Great explanation @Reza